# Make clean form submitted urls using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a url in the form of domain.com/?product=value1&product2=value2.....

Sometimes the textboxes may not have values in it. How can I ignore those forms elements using Javascript?

I want to avoid the `domain.com/?product=&product2=abs&product3=&product4=`

**my form**

```
    <form action="customsearch.php">

    <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="product" name="product">
    <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="product2" name="product2">
.
.
.    
    <input type="submit" value="Send">

    </form>
```

Comment: may I ask why you'd want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to make those clean urls because I use a script that slows down the page if it has a lot of fields in the url

Comment: Additionally, please show the code that you are using right now. By the sound of the question you already have something that only needs a small tweak.

Comment: Why do you send the form with GET at all? Most of the time, this is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe for the submit event of the form:

```
<form action="customsearch.php" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">
```

and remove empty elements:

```
function formSubmit() {
    var product = document.getElementById('product');
    var product2 = document.getElementById('product2');
    if (product.value == '') {
        product.parentNode.removeChild(product);
    }
    if (product2.value == '') {
        product2.parentNode.removeChild(product2);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Darin can you give me a full code example ? I am new in JS and dont know how to use it correctly.

Comment: @Mikey, in the `<head>` section put a `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` tag containing the `formSubmit` function and add the `onsubmit` attribute to the form.

Comment: Darin I have some problem on having products followed by number more than 9. I mean product10, product11, product12 are displayed in the url even if they are empty... the system just ignores them. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but keep in mind if the person cancels the submit, your form will not work as expected (unless you develop a way to restate the `name` attributes)...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function(event) {

   var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('input');

   for (var i = 0, inputsLength = inputs.length; i < inputsLength; i++) {
       if (inputs[i].value === '') {
           inputs[i].setAttribute('name', '');
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Alternatively, in your PHP file, drop the blank GET params and send `Location` header to the clean URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty textbox validation as

```
if(document.getElementById("product").value==""){
  // the value is empty.
}else{
  // the value is not empty.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about create another form?

1.press the submit button to create a form

2.check the input value. if not null, then create the input element then insert into the form

3.submit

Comment: By the way, you can make input name shorter. "product1" can be "p1".